# C# application automation

Tags: user-interface, automation, scheduled-tasks, datetimepicker, ui-automation

i have a windows forms application to backup certain files. 
Normally you hit the button "Start Backup" and the programm
will do whatever is selected as an option.

Now i have implemented via Task Sceduler DLL the possibility
to do the backup on a desired day and time via a datetimepicker
object.

So far i only found out how to register the the programm.exe
in Windows and it also starts up on the chosen time.

My question now is how would it be possible to be able to execute
the "Start Backup" button via automation or a script? All other needed
parameters for the programm are stored in Settings.Default values.

Code from the Task Scheduler, maybe there is a shorter way to solve
the problem?

```
        private void futureBackup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
        TaskService ts = new TaskService();
        TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
        Trigger t = new TimeTrigger();
        t.StartBoundary = System.DateTime.Now.Date
        +this.dateTimePicker1.Value.TimeOfDay;
        td.Triggers.Add(t);
        string path1 = Desktop + @"\Desktop\Release\Backup.exe";
        td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(path1, null, null));
        ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("XBackupX", td);
        ts.BeginInit();
    }
```

I found the UI Automation in Visual Studio but i am not exactly sure if that's what can fix the "problem"!?!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now the easiest way i came up with is to have
2 programm exe files... 2nd one is called backup_s.exe
which then is added to the task scheduler in windows.

only difference between the 2 codes is _s loads the last
options automatically from an xml file then executes the
start backup by trigger event and closes itself after 1
minute.